# Django syncdb on first deployment

Tags: python, django, deployment, django-models

So I've managed to create a site with django 1.8 and I'm ready to deploy. I have several new models and I'm using django-allauth which has it's own models. I've also managed to make changes to settings with a config file to use different databases for production and development as well as turning off debug when it's production, etc.

I've uploaded my project folder to the production server and getting ready to add new lines in http.conf for Apache but I can't wrap my head around the database.
Do I run syncdb or makemigrations on the production server? How does django know to use the production db and not the development db. My settings look for hostname from socket to decide if it's production or development.

What should I do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/):

> You should think of migrations as a version control system for your
>   database schema. `makemigrations` is responsible for packaging up your
>   model changes into individual migration files - analogous to commits -
>   and `migrate` is responsible for applying those to your database.
>
> The migration files for each app live in a “migrations” directory
>   inside of that app, and are designed to be committed to, and
>   distributed as part of, its codebase. You should be making them once
>   on your development machine and then running the same migrations on
>   your colleagues’ machines, your staging machines, and eventually your
>   production machines.

So, you make migrations on your dev machine and then run them on any other machine.

Comment: Right, I forgot about the migration files. So do I just go into the directory where the settings file is and run "django-admin migrate" on the production server after deployment?

Comment: Yes, or better `./manage.py migrate` if you are in linux or `manage.py migrate` on windows.

Comment: I figured it out. I ran python manage.py migrate on my production server and tables were created/changed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**syncdb** has been changed to **migrate** since django 1.7

> **Migrations**
> New in Django 1.7.
>
> Migrations are Django’s way of propagating changes you make to your models (adding a field, deleting a model, etc.) into your database schema. They’re designed to be mostly automatic, but you’ll need to know when to make migrations, when to run them, and the common problems you might run into.
>
> Prior to version 1.7, Django only supported adding new models to the database; it was not possible to alter or remove existing models via the **syncdb** command (the predecessor to **migrate**).

The difference betwen **migrate** and **makemigrations** is nicely stated by **doru**.